# Bootstrap-sass jquery error

Tags: jquery, typescript, gulp, webpack, bootstrap-sass

After couple of hours spent on trying to solve my problem I came here to get some help.

I'm trying to load Bootstrap javascript via webpack and gulp to my project, but I am receiving following **browser** error.

[image: error message]

Here is how my **webpack.config** looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [
            "",
            ".webpack.js",
            ".web.js",
            ".ts",
            ".tsx",
            ".js",
            ".scss"
        ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            }
        ]
    }

};
```

It perfectly loads jQuery, because I can use it but it seems that bootstrap-sass does not see it.

Here is how my **script.ts** look like:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
let bootstrap = require("../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js");
```

And lastly here is my **gulpfile.ts**:

```
gulp.task("ts", () => {
    gulp.src(["public/scripts/*.ts"]).
        pipe(webpack(require("./webpack.config.ts"))).
        pipe(uglify()).
        pipe(gulp.dest("public/scripts"));
});
```

I am so frustrated that it is not work.
I know that I can use bootstrap-sass-loader, but I prefer to compile my sass files via gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yohuuuu, I've finally found an answer. In order to let bootstrap-sass know about jquery I had to import jquery via this [loader.](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader)

1. Install loader via npm:

`npm install imports-loader`

2. Then add this line to your webpack.config.js:

`{test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, loader: "imports?jQuery=jquery"},`

Hope that will help you :)